# Webpage long list item impression

Tags: javascript, html, impressions

Say we have a long list, so some items may not be seen at the beginning.

After user scrolls the screen, some more items are seen.

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    --------not seen at the beginning-------
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    ....
</ul>
```

What is the best practice for judging which item is seen by the user?

Maybe known as Impression, but I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: You mean a technical way to detect which items are on screen? Or something more abstract about [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: May I ask why it is important to you to determine the visibility of those items? Just want to make sure we don't have an XY-Problem here.

Comment: probably just show the ones which could be visible in a viewport. if the user intents to scroll down then fetch the next ones until you rendered one not in the viewport anymore. Repeat...

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960082/position-of-div-in-relation-to-the-top-of-the-viewport -- also check [this](http://upshots.org/javascript/jquery-test-if-element-is-in-viewport-visible-on-screen) and [that](https://gist.github.com/jlong/eff01958791d3e0bf10c).

Comment: A technical way to detect which items are seen.

Comment: Since we have got a method "Element.scrollIntoView()".  

Is there some method like "isIntoView" avaliable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On any HTML element, you can get its position on the screen using `getBoundingClientRect()`:

```
const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
```

The result is an object with the properites `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`, `width` and `height`.

You should also check the window height:

```
const height = window.innerHeight;
```

Now, you can compare the `top` and `bottom` values of the element's bounding rect with the window height to determine if it's visible:

```
function isVisible(rect, height) {
    return rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom < height;
}
```

You may also want to check the percentage of the element that is shown (depends on when you decide to start counting impressions: full view or partial view as well).