# Sliding menubar according to mousewheel moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to slide the menubar according to the page scrolling.
Here is an example : [Sample Site](http://hammertechengineering.com/)

I want to do this menubar sliding effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this suggestion:

http://ruturaj.net/automatic-header-stick-to-scroll-with-jquery/

It seems to do exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, this one is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you, I'll accept this one as an answer.

Comment: That's for the upvote. If you feel it is what you are after, you could accept the answer too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you would position the menu bar "static" until the coordinates of that div/ul reach the viewport. Then you would position it "fixed".

This answer should be of help with regard to getting the coordinates.[How do I calculate the width between two elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896297/how-do-i-calculate-the-width-between-two-elements/)